Causal Reconciliation: Is this a viable way for my FTL system to preserve the course of History?
This was kind of inspired by Singularity Sky, as well as Halo for having the concept of 'causal reconciliation' even if it's just a throw away handwave with little elaboration.
The premise is this, FTL is possible and violates causality, but at the same time our universe is also alive and proactive in maintaining its history.
In order to travel FTL, ships must enter hyperspace and navigate what are known as Ways, which are sort of like the Universe's root system, which connect every point in time and space with every other point in time and space.
For example, say humanity finds a Way that can be plotted between the Sol System and a system, 2000 light years away we'll call Aurea.
The ship leaves our System. This is the Starting Date.
When the ship arrives at Aurea, it arrives roughly 2000 years in the future, as though it had travelled at near light speeds. lets call this Arrival Date.  If you pointed a telescope with near perfect clarity back at Earth, the only information you'd get is after the Starting Date
But the real trouble begins when you travel via the same Way. Instead of another 2000 years in the future, you'd arrive roughly 2000 years in the past, around the Starting Time plus the time spent on the other side. This would be called a local causality violation and can be healed.
At no point can you follow a Way back to before the Starting Date and breach global causality. In this case, instead of healing, it would trigger the cosmological immune system and the Ways would annihilate anything trying to enter.
Now what happens if you tried to find a Way to Earth from Aurea 2000 years in the future, and then tried to zig zag back to the Starting Point via the first Way? Same result. Immediately the Way might collapse on you as your afflicted with what is called Counterfactual Contamination. That is, the universe notices that you have the mere potential to give Earth around the Starting Date information on its own future.
That or you'd find yourself arriving in Aurea 2000 years after the Arrival Date. Though its probably more convenient for me if the ship simply gets destroyed.
This is basically my explanation. Truth be told I'm not sure how viable it is, as when I put thought into it I realize that there are a lot of unknown unknowns for me when the scenario is scaled up to include multiple systems or FTL happening with different starting points and reference frames. The basic rule remains the same, at the bare minimum, no reference frame should ever be be able to alter its own history.
Is this a viable explanation for me to have somewhat casual interstellar travel while at the same time meeting the above condition? Or is there something fatal that breaks everything I'm missing here?

The idea that a wormhole network can't form causality-violating loops is discussed in this neat post, which doesn't require the network to "know" which way ships are moving — it just disallows any closed loop from A to B to C to A, which is what causes problems.

Generally, people care much less about how the FTL system works than that it works. Just handwave a functioning wormhole system and add whatever qualifiers you need for your story, then paste some semi-cohesive technobabble in the gaps and you're good to go. Until we find actual wormholes in real life, writing hard sci-fi about them will be very difficult.

If you hover your mouse over the [tag:internal-consistency] and [tag:science-fiction] tags you will discover they are mutually exclusive. You must choose one or the other. I recommend you delete [tag:internal-consistency] because that tag has specific rules and a specific purpose and you're not meeting either. Please read the tag wikis. Thanks.

I think you're going to have to do some more work on this.

But the real trouble begins when you travel via the same Way. Instead of another 2000 years in the future, you'd arrive roughly 2000 years in the past, around the Starting Time plus the time spent on the other side.

How does the universe "know" that you're travelling back to your starting point, and send you into the past rather than the future?
Is the answer different if you mine Aurea and build a robot ship that will travel back to your starting point with the information you've given it, but none of the matter that has travelled from the starting point?

I should've made it more explicit, but the Universe is alive and even intelligent in its own. In that sense, the Ways are almost analogous to a nervous or circulatory system, there are countless numbers of them but only some are viable for travel. If you find one that can open, then the others react, calculate and change to prevent contamination.

@AllSeeingEye33: Please edit that into the question. It makes a huge difference.

@AllSeeingEye33 You just threw out causality.

@Trish could you elaborate?

@AllSeeingEye33 Any item that exists interacts with things around it. All those interactions happen at the speed of light (as in reflecting light) or less. All those interactions happen inside the light cone of the event. If an event happens inside the future light cone of another, then the first event can cause the 2nd. If the 2nd event is in your events past light cone, then your event can be caused by the 2nd event you look at. That is Causality. However, events also exist independant from one another.

Your whole suggestion you could return to the event at the start would violate causality and the Minkowski-space, which is the whole light cone thing I just explained. Causality disallows ANYTHING from traveling faster than light, including information.

@AllSeeingEye33: If the universe has the power to choose to violate causality, then some people are going to worship it as God. Also, much of science becomes pointless, because the universe may choose to behave differently.

One way to go around it, which does not required Sentient Universes and other Deus Ex solutions, is branching timelines.

Ship goes from Earth to Aurea - ok
Ship tries to go back to Earth in a way that would be time travel to the past, then:
from external observer's perspective the time-travelling ship vanished from existence.
From the perspective of the ship's crew, they traveled to the past, and created a new timeline, branching, rather than violating causality.

It thus becomes "common knowledge" that any attempt to travel back before your Starting Date is essentially a very expensive form of suicide: it either seems to not work (if you just try to send information) or the offending craft blips out of the universe forever.
Unknowingly to just about everyone except some theoretical physicists, these time-travellers did not cease to exist, just went to/created a new timeline, and cannot go back.
This allows you to have your cake and eat it too: the causality in the "main" universe seems perfectly preserved with no need for Space Gods to intervene (though it might seem like an Act of God to an observer). All the same, the violators of causality end up in branching timelines rather than dead, allowing you to continue their stories at your leisure.
